# Use of Views slowing down site

Tags: drupal-7, view

Not sure if I am correct or not but i found that my site nerdeky.com which is using a view to show latest nodes on front page is crashing because of the views process of loading all nodes at once.

I have a content type called "Nerdeky Info" which contains more than 500 posts. To show latest 12 posts on frontpage i created a view and applied pager for rest of the posts. It was working good untill i had 100 or 200 posts but now it is slow in loading and sometimes crashes. I have New Relic integrated with my server and i can see that whenever site crashes it reports that the view took most of the time to process php and database.

After some searching on forum i found that my view is currently loading all posts at once and showing nerdeky latest posts afterwards.

Please suggest how to make it light so that only latest posts load first.

Thanks
Bharat sharma

Comment: Try enabling use ajax option in views.

Comment: I did, the pager you can see working on nerdeky.com home page using ajax option of views.